# Homebrew installed: geoiplookup shows no output - howto install GeoIP-data?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, geolocation

```
> geoipupdate; geoiplookup 8.8.4.4
> echo $?
0
```

It does not print any output. According [this posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198524/26612) there should be GeoIP-data. Howto use that on macOS?

```
> brew search geoip
geoip                                                                                                                                geoipupdate
homebrew/nginx/geoip2-nginx-module    homebrew/php/php53-geoip              homebrew/php/php54-geoip              homebrew/php/php55-geoip              homebrew/php/php56-geoip              homebrew/php/php70-geoip              homebrew/php/php71-geoip
```

No such package. Howto use geoiplookup on macOS / Homebrew?

```
> brew info geoip
geoip: stable 1.6.9 (bottled), HEAD
This library is for the GeoIP Legacy format (dat)
https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c
/usr/local/Cellar/geoip/1.6.9 (17 files, 548.9K) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-01-21 at 19:22:56
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/geoip.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: geoipupdate ✔
==> Options
--universal
        Build a universal binary
--with-geoipupdate
        Build with geoipupdate support
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
> brew info geoipupdate
geoipupdate: stable 2.3.1 (bottled), HEAD
Automatic updates of GeoIP2 and GeoIP Legacy databases
https://github.com/maxmind/geoipupdate
/usr/local/Cellar/geoipupdate/2.3.1 (13 files, 83.7K) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-01-21 at 19:25:04
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/geoipupdate.rb
==> Options
--universal
        Build a universal binary
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
```

I wish to use local Geo data, not query an external web hosted API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After installing geoipupdate and geoip with geoipupdate support navigate to the file `/usr/local/Cellar/geoipupdate/2.3.1/etc/GeoIP.conf` and open it.

Replace:

```
# Please see http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/ for instructions
# on setting up geoipupdate, including information on how to download a
# pre-filled GeoIP.conf file.

# Enter your user ID and license key below. These are available from
# https://www.maxmind.com/en/my_license_key. If you are only using free
# GeoLite databases, you make leave the 0 values.
UserId 0
LicenseKey 000000000000

# Enter the product IDs of the databases you would like to update.
# Multiple product IDs are separated by spaces.
ProductIds GeoLite2-Country GeoLite2-City
...
```

with:

```
# The following UserId and LicenseKey are required placeholders:
UserId 999999
LicenseKey 000000000000

# Include one or more of the following ProductIds:
# * GeoLite2-City - GeoLite 2 City
# * GeoLite2-Country - GeoLite2 Country
# * GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-City - GeoLite Legacy IPv6 City
# * GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-Country - GeoLite Legacy IPv6 Country
# * 506 - GeoLite Legacy Country
# * 517 - GeoLite Legacy ASN
# * 533 - GeoLite Legacy City
ProductIds GeoLite2-City GeoLite2-Country GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-City GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-Country 506 517 533
...
```

and update the database with `geoipupdate`.

Entering `geoiplookup 8.8.4.4` now will yield:

```
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: US, N/A, N/A, N/A, N/A, 37.750999, -97.821999, 0, 0
```

---

Update:

According to adejones' comment the GeoIP.conf file moved to `/usr/local/etc/GeoIP.conf` in newer versions of "brew-installed" *geoipupdate*.

Comment: Worked for me on macOS 10.13.3 using brew 1.5.3, geoipupdate 2.5.0 however the geoipupdate conf file is located here: `/usr/local/etc/GeoIP.conf`

Comment: @adejones Thanx for the update. I added an addendum...

Comment: Uncommented and set first number accordingly, doesn't work.
```
8 AccountID 999999
9 LicenseKey 000000000000
```
```
~ ls /usr/local/Cellar/geoipupdate/
3.1.1/
~ brew --version
Homebrew 1.8.3
~ brew info geoip
geoip: stable 1.6.12 (bottled), HEAD
...
/usr/local/Cellar/geoip/1.6.12 (18 files, 548.9KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-11-25 at 11:57:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/geoip.rb
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I still can not understand how I made this work, and why is it so unintuitive,

This is what I did:

```
  brew install geoipupdate
  brew install libmaxminddb
```

then

```
mmdblookup -i xx.xx.xx.xx -f /usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
```

Comment: where do you get the db files from? `Can't open /usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb - Error opening the specified MaxMind DB file`

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/maxmind/mmdbinspect with databases from https://github.com/wp-statistics/GeoLite2-City:

```
mmdbinspect -db "$database_file" "$ip"
```

You can use `jq` to further process the output.